# Are questions about entomophagy (insect-eating) on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions about entomophagy (insect-eating) on topic? Here are the questions:

- [What do you call an almost vegetarian diet that includes honey and insects, but excludes milk and eggs?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/78/what-do-you-call-an-almost-vegetarian-diet-that-includes-honey-and-insects-but)
- [Can those who eat insects be considered vegetarians?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/20/can-those-who-eat-insects-be-considered-vegetarians)
- [Are insects a feasible source of proteins for the new millennium?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/649/are-insects-a-feasible-source-of-proteins-for-the-new-millennium)
- [Are insects a better source of any nutrients than plant-based foods?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1536/are-insects-a-better-source-of-any-nutrients-than-plant-based-foods)

Here's a quick summary of past discussions and related precedent to guide discussion.

- The community consensus in Meta is that [sorta-vegetarian diets are on-topic](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15/1236).
- We have a [pescatarianism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pescatarianism) tag for people who eat fish...
- ... even though we agreed [pescatarian diets are not vegetarian](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/37/1236).
- Nic votes to close [insects a feasible source of protein](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/649/are-insects-a-feasible-source-of-proteins-for-the-new-millennium#comment2742_649), but Alexander Rossa votes to leave open because it "has relevance when it comes to the scope of this site".
- Nic [suggests](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/260/1236) that same "insects feasible source of protein" question is off-topic and should have been migrated to Sustainability.SE. [Zanna agrees](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257/add-related-sites-on-stackexchange-to-our-faq-for-on-topic-questions?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment538_260) that it was off-topic.
- NogShine [expresses disdain in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44585631#44585631) after seeing a question about insect-eating. Zanna agrees, "[that's not vegetarian](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44585649#44585649)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Questions about insect-eating must be comparative, not instructive.**

Or as [Zanna would say](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44586199#44586199)...

> when people start asking for insect recipes I might start voting to close them

Insects are part of the animal kingdom, and are part of the phylum [arthropoda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthropod) which also includes crustaceans (crab, shrimp, lobster). We should treat questions about insect-eating the same as other questions about animal-eating, so let's take a look at that.

This aligns with our current stance on questions about meat-eating. It's fine within the scope of the site to ask questions which compare meat-eating with vegetarianism and we have some examples of that already.

- [Is meat protein really "better" than protein from a vegan or vegetarian source?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/400/1236)
- [Are there any studies that show differences in health benefits between a low meat eater flexitarian and other vegetarians types?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/669/1236)
- [Do I really help by eating no meat but still eating fish ? How much is my environmental footprint reduced?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/1445/1236)

However, it is *not* acceptable to ask questions which invite answers that provide instruction about eating meat. Those questions would be more suitable for [Cooking.SE](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/).

In fact, we should accept comparative questions even when it seems like there is a chance that the answer [may not reflect positively](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1405/does-growing-crops-kill-more-animals-than-raising-cows-on-pasture) on vegetarianism. People come to Stack Exchange for accuracy, not propaganda, and it's essential that we provide an accurate picture of vegetarianism.

---

**Analysis of Specific Questions**

[What do you call an almost vegetarian diet that includes honey and insects, but excludes milk and eggs?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/78/1236)

This is a terminology question that [overlaps with taxonomy](http://contentrules.com/taxonomy-terminology-controlled-vocabulary/) and taxonomy is entirely about comparing entities for similarities and differences. The question does not ask for instruction about eating insects. This question is acceptable.

[Can those who eat insects be considered vegetarians?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/20/1236)

This is a question about establishing what is/isn't vegetarian, and we don't yet have a community consensus about [whether to allow questions defining what is/isn't vegetarian](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28/should-we-allow-questions-on-defining-what-is-isnt-vegetarian). It might be off-topic for that reason, but it's not off-topic just because it mentions eating insects for the same reason as above.

[Are insects a feasible source of proteins for the new millennium?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/649/1236)

This question seeks to compare vegan diets against vegan+insect diets on the basis of sustainability. Sustainability is a motivating factor for a subset of vegans and this is on-topic because it establishes a comparison against veganism.

[Are insects a better source of any nutrients than plant-based foods?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/1536/1236)

This is a direct comparison of insect-based foods against plant-based foods on a nutritional basis. However, this question skirts the line about being instructive by providing a link to a specific provider of insect-based food. That's just a little bit too helpful for people who are thinking about eating insects, and should probably be discouraged.

Comment: Based on this rationale, I think [this question](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/120/what-are-the-steps-a-vegetarian-vegan-should-take-to-start-eating-meat-again) about how to start eating meat should be closed.